# Как в боте для ВК сделать чтобы бот ввёл первое сообщение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Вот так примерно, бот написал первое сообщение, а потом я дальше продолжил диалог [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
while True:
try:
    if messages["count"] >= 1:
        id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
        body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
        if body.lower() == "привет":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif body.lower() == "кто ты?":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Я бот", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        if body.lower() == "что делаешь?":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ничего", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        if body.lower() == "как дела?":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Плохо конечно же!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        if body.lower() == "почему?":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Сам незнаю =)", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        if body.lower() == "это не ты":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Да потому что я не ты", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        if body.lower() == "ок":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "ок ,_,", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        if body.lower() == "расскажи анекдот":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "— Помоги мне сидеть на диете – сказала жена мужу, в надежде на то, что они вместе будут правильно питаться и морально поддерживать друг друга. — Без проблем – сказал муж, и в одно лицо сожрал всю еду в холодильнике. anekdotov.net", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        if body.lower() == "":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "ок ,_,", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Это делается в настройках сообщества. Во вкладке сообщения. Нужно включить сообщения сообщества, и написать в приветствие) Это сообщения будет отправлено когда пользователь зайдёт в чат